# iOS8 EXC_BAD_ACCESS when executing [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:argList]

Tags: ios8, xcode6

The following code works fine on iOS7. And it crashes when I run on Xcode6/iOS.

```
+ (void)log:(NSString *)format arguments:(va_list)argList
{   
    NSLogv(format, argList);

    if ([self sharedConsole].enabled)
    {
        NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:argList]; //Crash here with info of EXC_BAD_ACCESS
        if ([NSThread currentThread] == [NSThread mainThread])
        {   
            [[self sharedConsole] logOnMainThread:message];
        }
        else
        {
            [[self sharedConsole] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(logOnMainThread:)
                                                   withObject:message waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same problem for me !

NSLogv's implementation changes on iOS8

My solution : close va_list and reinit it between every uses.

```
+ (void)log:(NSString *)format arguments:(va_list)argList
{   
    va_start(argList,format) ;
    NSLogv(format, argList);
    va_end(argList) ;

    va_start(argList,format) ;
    if ([self sharedConsole].enabled)
    {
        NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:argList]; //Crash here with info of EXC_BAD_ACCESS
        if ([NSThread currentThread] == [NSThread mainThread])
        {   
            [[self sharedConsole] logOnMainThread:message];
        }
        else
        {
            [[self sharedConsole] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(logOnMainThread:)
                                                   withObject:message waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
    }
    va_end(argList) ;
}
```

(Tof, previously @user2424230)

Answer (score 2):

As user2424230 pointed out the argument list has to be reinitialized. If your method was variadic, you could've used va_start and va_end. However, it seems that you are initializing and passing a va_list from outside. In this case you can copy the list like this:

```
+ (void)log:(NSString *)format arguments:(va_list)argList
{
    va_list internalArgs;

    va_copy(internalArgs, argList);
    NSLogv(format, internalArgs);
    va_end(internalArgs);

    va_copy(internalArgs, argList);
    if ([self sharedConsole].enabled)
    {
        NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:internalArgs];
        if ([NSThread currentThread] == [NSThread mainThread])
        {   
            [[self sharedConsole] logOnMainThread:message];
        }
        else
        {
            [[self sharedConsole] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(logOnMainThread:)
                                                   withObject:message waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
    }
    va_end(internalArgs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common case for initWithFormat:arguments: crashes is when the format string contains more parameters than the arguments specified.